# Products are not shown on product detailed page

Tags: magento2, products

Products added from admin panel are shown in the product list in admin panel, but not reflected on web frontend.

I have installed a design theme in my magento setup and also clicking on any product in that theme, shows "This page isn't working, HTTP 500 error".

Comment: Some error is occured on your theme. Can you apply default luma theme and check if its working correctly or not?

Comment: I tried the default luma theme, it works correctly. So would it be the problem with my theme?

Comment: Yes it must be with your theme. Rename the Magento_Catalog directory under your theme and test.

Comment: to trace the reasons of 500 error, you can `switch to developer mode` and `enable system log`. path :  `stores-->configuration-->advanced-->developer-->debug-->log to file`. after enabling log to file please check the log files in the `var/log` directory. it should point something to your custom theme.